# Updating test in xml file with php textarea submit

Tags: php, xml, dom

Need help with xml file to edit content for my flash site, every time when I insert into textarea for example "name" it create new activity in xml and I need that it would **change from "swimming" to "name"**.
I have found out that to change content in xml I need to **delete "swimming" and to insert "Name"** .

**How to do it, first to insert content into textarea --> save it when you press "update" --> delete old activity from xml file and than to insert new content into xml file????**

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <activity>swimming</activity>
</list>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
</head>

<body>


<table width="100" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><?php
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load("sample.xml", LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

    $activities = $xmldoc->firstChild->firstChild;
    if($activities!=null){
        while($activities!=null){
            echo $activities->textContent."";
            $activities = $activities->nextSibling;
        }
    }
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form name="input" action="insert.php" method="post">

      <textarea name="activity" cols="70" rows="10"><?php
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load("sample.xml", LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

    $activities = $xmldoc->firstChild->firstChild;
    if($activities!=null){
        while($activities!=null){
            echo $activities->textContent."";
            $activities = $activities->nextSibling;
        }
    }
?></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Update"/>
  <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
</form></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
    header('Location:index.php');
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');

    $newAct = $_POST['activity'];

    $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

    $newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('activity');
    $root->appendChild($newElement);
    $newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
    $newElement->appendChild($newText);

    $xmldoc->save('sample.xml');
?>
```

Thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: You're not HTML-escaping `echo $activities->textContent."";`. OTOH kudos for using DOMDocument for XML rather than some regexp mess :)

Answer (score 1):

okay i have managed by myself, if you need to add or delete content on your web page just copy all from top except insert.php

new insert.php

```
<?php 
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument;
$xmldoc->load('sample.xml');
foreach ($xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('activity') as $activity)
{
    $activity->parentNode->removeChild($activity);
}
$xmldoc->save('sample.xml');

?>

<?php

    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');

    $newAct = $_POST['activity'];

    $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

    $newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('activity');
    $root->appendChild($newElement);
    $newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
    $newElement->appendChild($newText);

    $xmldoc->save('sample.xml');

?>
```

that's all thanks